# Can't read Label value in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, null, label

I have read many posts here looking for the answer.  But no matter what I do I always get a null value returned for my Label.

I can populate it just fine and read it at that time, but when I try to read the label to populate DB it is always null.

aspx code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TOTAL YIELD" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="130">
  <EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lb_TotalYield" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
  </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

in the code behind I am just trying to read it.

```
foreach (GridViewRow currentRow in gv_Fruit.Rows)
{
Label tempLabel = (Label)currentRow.FindControl("lb_TotalValue") as Label;
string theTotalValue = tempLabel.Text; 
}
```

for complete information Here is how I set the label:

```
myGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text = myTotalYield;
```

I have tried doing a gv_RowDataBound, but it doesn't seem to ever be called.

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (myGridView.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex &&
      e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      Label mylabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lb_TotalYield");
      mylabel.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Comment: When the code in your second example is executing, are you sure you're in Edit mode? I believe the label would only be present if a particular row is being edited since you have it in the EditItemTemplate.

Comment: This may just be a typo, but you've got "lb_TotalValue" instead of "lb_TotalYield" in your first FindControl line

Comment: How do I tell if I am in "Edit" mode?

Comment: @Melanie - Yes it is a cut/paste error.